# What is the difference between these two FOL statements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

Suppose I want to translate the following english statement to first order logic:

> Every student loves some student.

What is the difference between these two:

- ∀x[Student(x) → ∃y[Student(y) ∧ Loves(x,y)]]
- ∀x∃y Student(x) → (Loves(x,y) ∧ Student(y))

  Does the separation of the quantifiers make a difference?

Comment: There's no difference, though it may sound weird - in the natrual language context - that the second form requires the existence of $y$ even if $x$ is not a student (but it doesn''t demand romance or studentship)

Comment: if $x$ is not a variable in $A$ then $A\vee[\exists x B\left(x\right)]$ is the same as $\exists x A\vee B\left(x\right)$

Comment: @hagenvoneitzen I understand what you mean, but could you point to where exactly in the second form that implies that?